# Asymptotic curves on the surface generated by $f(u,v)=(v\cos u,v\sin u,e^u)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm learning differential geometry recently and I met an exercise below. It is a question for asymptotic curve.

**Question**:

A map $f: \mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is defined by
$$f(u,v)=(v\cos(u),v\sin(u),e^u)$$

We denote the surface generated by this map as $S$. We call a smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ on $S$ an *asymptotic curve* if the acceleration vector $\gamma^{\prime\prime}(t)$ is always tangent to the surface $S$.

1. We parameterize the smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ on $S$ by $u(t)$, $v(t)$ as $$\gamma(t) = f(u(t),v(t))$$
   Under what condition can the curve $\gamma(t)$ be an asymptotic curve. Show it by the differential equation.
2. For any point $p$ on $S$, and two asymptotic curves through this $p$, show that the following situation is possible: The velocity vector of two asymptotic curves are linearly independent. And find two asymptotic curves for $p=(1,0,1)$.

$\mathbf{What\,I\,have\,done}$

I hope it is right that the differential equation for the first question should be
$$2v^\prime=u^\prime v$$
I got stuck at the second question.

For a point on a regular 2-dimentional surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, how many asymptotic curves through this point exist?

Thanks!

**Update 2020_06_09**

My solution to the first question:

$f^{\prime}(t)=$
$$[v^{\prime}cos(u)-vu^{\prime}sin(u),$$

$$v^{\prime}sin(u)+vu^{\prime}cos(u),$$

$$u^{\prime}e^u]$$

$f^{\prime\prime}(t)=$

$$[v^{\prime\prime}cos(u)-2v^{\prime}u^{\prime}sin(u)-vu^{\prime\prime}sin(u)-v(u^{\prime})^2cos(u),$$

$$v^{\prime\prime}sin(u)+2v^{\prime}u^{\prime}cos(u)+vu^{\prime\prime}cos(u)-v(u^{\prime})^2sin(u),$$

$$((u^{\prime})^2+u^{\prime\prime})e^u]$$

$f_u(u,v)= (-vsin(u), vcos(u), e^u)$

$f_v(u,v)= (cos(u), sin(u), 0)$

$\vec{n} (u,v)=f_u\times f_v = (-e^u sin(u), e^u cos(u), -v)$

from the definition of asymptotic curve we know that, $f^{\prime\prime}(t)\cdot \vec{n}=0$ ,then

$$-[v^{\prime\prime}cos(u)-2v^{\prime}u^{\prime}sin(u)-vu^{\prime\prime}sin(u)-v(u^{\prime})^2cos(u)]\cdot e^u sin(u) +$$

$$[v^{\prime\prime}sin(u)+2v^{\prime}u^{\prime}cos(u)+vu^{\prime\prime}cos(u)-v(u^{\prime})^2sin(u)]\cdot e^u cos(u) -$$

$$[(u^{\prime})^2+u^{\prime\prime}]\cdot e^u v] = 0$$

$so, 2v^{\prime}=u^{\prime}v$

For the second question, thanks for reminder from  Professor Theodore Shifrin, I calculate the Gauss Curvature for this surface:

$K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}$

$f_u(u,v)= (-vsin(u), vcos(u), e^u)$

$f_{uu}(u,v)= (-vcos(u), -vsin(u), e^u)$

$f_v(u,v)= (cos(u), sin(u), 0)$

$f_{vv}(u,v)= (0, 0, 0)$

$f_{uv}(u,v)= (-sin(u), cos(u), 0)$

$\vec{n} (u,v)=\frac{f_u\times f_v}{|f_u\times f_v|} = \frac{(-e^u sin(u), e^u cos(u), -v)}{\sqrt{e^{2u} + v^2}}$

L=$f_{uu}\cdot \vec{n}$, M=$f_{uv}\cdot \vec{n}$, N=$f_{vv}\cdot \vec{n}$

E=$r_u\cdot r_u$, F=$r_u\cdot r_v$, G=$r_v\cdot r_v$

So,

$$K=-\frac{e^{2u}}{(e^{2u}+v^2)^2} \lt 0$$

Comment: Please show your work. At a hyperbolic point ($K<0$), there are two distinct asymptotic directions. At a non-planar parabolic point ($K=0$), there is one asymptotic direction. Exercise for you: Lines contained in a surface are always asymptotic curves.

Comment: Thanks for @TedShifrin 's advice and I will continue to update my work if I can do more.

Comment: And thanks for @Blue's edit, I would like to try more to manage my formatting.